# D3 transition stop in the middle of dragend event

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

Can anyone help with this situation?
I have two circles, one inside the other that should move together when I drag the outer one.
The inner circle should appear only when the mouse is over the outer circle.
When the drag is finished, both circles should go back to origin position.
Here is fiddle with an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gluz/DS4aw/).
And here is the code for it:

```
    var deg90 = Math.PI / 2,
ptOuter = [200, 250],
rOuter = 70,
rInner = 10;

var ptInner = innerCircleXY(ptOuter[0],ptOuter[1],rOuter,rInner);

var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("drag", function () {
    var c2NewX=parseInt(outerCircle.attr("cx"),10) + d3.event.dx;
    var c2NewY=parseInt(outerCircle.attr("cy"),10) + d3.event.dy;
    var icNewX=parseInt(innerCircle.attr("cx"),10) + d3.event.dx;
    var icNewY=parseInt(innerCircle.attr("cy"),10) + d3.event.dy;

    outerCircle.attr({
        "cx": c2NewX,
        "cy": c2NewY
    });
    innerCircle.attr({"cx":icNewX, "cy":icNewY});
})
.on("dragend",function() {
    innerCircle.transition().attr({"cx": ptInner[0],"cy": ptInner[1]});
    outerCircle.transition().attr({"cx": ptOuter[0],"cy": ptOuter[1]});
});

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

var outerCircle = svg.append('circle').attr({
    cx: ptOuter[0],
    cy: ptOuter[1],
    r: rOuter,
    fill: '#FFA300',
    stroke: '#FFA300',
    "stroke-width": 0})
    .style({'cursor': 'pointer'})
    .call(drag);

var innerCircle = svg.append('circle').attr({
    "id":"clicks",
    cx: ptInner[0],
    cy: ptInner[1],
    r: rInner,
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: '#666666',
    "stroke-width": 1,
    "stroke-opacity": 0.9})
    .style({'cursor': 'pointer', 'opacity':'0.0'});

outerCircle.on("mouseover", function(){innerCircle.transition().style({'opacity':'1.0'}).duration(300);});
outerCircle.on("mouseout", function(){innerCircle.transition().style({'opacity':'0.0'}).duration(300);});
```

function innerCircleXY(oX, oY, oR, iR) {
    var rDiff = Math.abs(oR - iR);
    var angle = Math.PI/3; // 60 degrees
    var x = oX + rDiff*Math.sin(angle);
    var y = oY + rDiff*Math.cos(angle);
    return ([x,y]);
}

The problem is that when I drag the outer circle and release, the inner circle doesn't go all the way back, but stop in the middle.
I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

**--> UPDATE <--**
This happens arbitrary and could be a case of specific OS or browser (for me it is OSX with chrome or safari).

Here is a [screencast](https://s3.amazonaws.com/gluz-public/circles_move_together_demo.mov) of what happens on my computer.

Comment: Your jsfiddle works fine for me.

Comment: Try drag it a few times.
Could the problem be only in specific OS or browser?

Comment: Could be, it works fine for me consistently in Chrome.

Comment: I've added a screencast of my computer when the problem occurs.
See the update at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The screencast doesn't work for me, but I think the problem is this line (and also the mouseover line, but its less likely to happen)...

```
outerCircle.on("mouseout", function(){innerCircle.transition().style({'opacity':'0.0'}).duration(300);});
```

I think what is probably happening is that the transition is conflicting with the previous transition thats taking place, if you move the mouse, so it feels intermittent, as this doesn't always happen.

So you may need to have a think about what you want to happen in this case. If you comment the line out, I think it should work ok (without the opacity change).

Comment: I believe you are right but I want that the circles will come back to their places once I release the button and that the inner circle will disappear once the mouse is not on the outer circle. How can I do it differently?

Comment: Maybe I'd be tempted to rejig it a bit, so that you have a group element with both circles in it (which also has the handler on it), and then transform that circleGroup. So you do a transform on the circle group, so they will always stick together whatever. Then you can just fade in/out the smaller circle with a separate transition ?